# Visual studio 2013 crash

Tags: visual-studio

Have big problem with my VS2013. It is crashing everytime when starting.
Application Name: devenv.exe

Application Version: 12.0.21005.1

The time stamp applications: 524fcb34

Name of the module with an error: StackHash_5861

Version of the module with an error: 0.0.0.0

The time stamp module with the error: 00000000

Offset exceptions: PCH_A9_FROM_ntdll + 0x0003AAAC

Exception code: c0000005

These exceptions: 00000008

OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.16.7

Language Code: 1049

Additional Information 1: 5861

2 For more information: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2

For more information, 3: 84a0

For more information, 4: 84a09ea102a12ee665c500221db8c9d

Look all theams at this forum and didn't help nothing.
Anybody know how to take off this error?

Comment: This may seem like a nitpick, but it's not actually a forum. It's a Q&A site, and you have put enough data into your question for it to be answered, preferably without extra discussion. I don't quite understand what you're asking here. Is it a problem running some of your code in VS? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Honestly, you will probably need to reinstall Windows. Common errors include having to run 2 copies of MSVC on the same system and removing one.

Comment: Mikhailm,are russian.right?Так может по русски поговорим?Now, in the case:sry for data. So,i have HYPER-V VM WS2012 R2 Datacenter, this is serios development environment for ECM Directum and i can't reinstall windows.

Comment: I just trying run my visual studio 2013. I am try to run devenv.exe /log and get error. I try to run devenv.exe /safemode and etc= error.

Comment: Sry,but what is MSVC?

Comment: I am experiencing the same error. Any fix?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably ask support on MSDN (Microsoft Developer Network) forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?category=visualstudio.

Comment: ye,i wrote there,but ppl don't know.